# Template Source Control Repository

Tags: git, github, templates

What is the best practice, for creating a template repository, and then creating *n* projects based on that template?

With "template" I mean: Let's say the template site is *x*. So *x* is a site with features that many new sites will have in common, and would want to utilise. For example, features like login, authentication service, swagger docs etc. So, when I make a online store *y*, I want to use *x* as a template and build the rest of the features on top of that. Then I might want to make a forum site *z*, and also use all the features of *x*

So it's *similar* to inheritance, in the sense that I want to make *n* repos derived from *x* (template). But a change in *x*, does not have to update *y* or *z*.

For example, I created a repo with this template for a website on Github: [repo](https://github.com/DivanVanZyl/BlazorWasmTemplate)

Now, I could fork off this repo, and work on the fork of the repo. But, it seems that gitHub is not really set up for a (free) user to do multiple forks of the same repo: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119733/how-can-i-make-a-second-fork-of-a-github-project)

I imagine one could clone the project, delete the source control assets (.git folder), and then upload it as a new repo.

To be clear, I do **not** want to pull changes from the original template, like some sort of repo inheritance, as described here: [similar post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197854/working-with-multiple-versions-of-websites-git)

Comment: Could you make clear what you mean by "a template repository" in the question itself? Posts that only make sense after following links are strongly discouraged here.

Comment: I updated the question, so that it is clearer. With "template" I basically mean a repo, that I can use to build upon, for many seperate repos in the future.

Comment: Honestly, "What is the best practice" is not really like an answerable question. You want to clone one project multiple times, fine, go ahead. Do you have a *specific* issue with this? Then ask about it.

Comment: @DocBrown Not a spefic issue, besides the manual steps seems non-optimal. And, there is not source control metadata linking the new projects to the original. Based on what you commented, it seems that you are not aware of another method besides cloning the project.  If another method in source control exists, that specifically addresses this scenario, then that would probably be the best practice. If not, then "cloning" would be the only way I am aware of. In that case, I would clone it and delete the source control metadata, in order to create a new repo for it.

Comment: Why do the steps have to be manual?  It sounds like they could be built into a script

Comment: This is possible with gitbub.  Link to documentation... https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-template-repository

Comment: There's no need to delete the source control assets. You can git pull from one repo and push to the other. It means the new repo will have a copy of the history of the old repo, but that's probably not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is what I was looking for:
[image]

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my!

short answer: Keep the template as small as humanly possible.

---

Inevitably, after a year or three, you will look back
on today's decisions and wonder "what was I thinking?"
Since you *know* you'll be learning new things and fixing bugs,
versioning is key.
And a versioned release is different from a template.
Issue releases of login libraries and similar utilities,
following [SemVer](https://semver.org).
Each project repo will pull in its own version of its own copy.

> a change in x, does not have to update y or z.

Yes! No need for y to accept potentially destabilizing
bug fixes when they become available.
But it should be *easy* to pull them in when y has a need
for some fix or feature, and y is in a position to
do acceptance testing.

---

The template repo *will* change as months go by.
Consider including a "checker" script (a "lint" script)
which verifies that directories are where we expect them
and that certain minimum requirements are met,
such as the "usual" config files being in conventional locations.

Now it is easy for y or z to run that check and
notice there's zero diffs, or there's one diff and
maybe I care about it right now, maybe I don't.

---

Creating new project repos is the least of your worries.
That's easy, it's just a matter of writing a script
and mentioning it in your standard-operating-procedure ReadMe.

A new repo might start this way. (I'm assuming you have
several repos checked out at the same directory level,
so they are all siblings.)
Begin by asking github to create empty repo X, which we'll clone.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/your-org/x.git
$ cd x
$ ls  # (Notice that it is nearly empty, maybe just a LICENSE.)
$ ../template/bin/new_project.sh
```

The new-project bash script could `mkdir` and so on,
but more simply it could just `rsync` the template
file hierarchy into the current working directory.
It might do a sanity check, like verifying
current directory is empty, before it overwrites anything.

I will emphasize again that the things it recursively
copies should mostly be *references* to code,
rather than lots of source code.
We all know that code is made of bugs,
bugs sometimes get fixed,
and chasing down a hundred bug fixes
in a hundred repos is nobody's idea of fun.

Be careful out there!